# NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid:

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am using python to call some power system simulation software(CYME).
I created a .py file to run the simulation and then I was trying to create a .exe file using py2exe. I do not get any errors running .py file and I get correct output.

But after creating .exe file and trying to run it I get the following output.

```
  Exception in Tkinter callback
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1538, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
    File "GUI.py", line 236, in run_scenarios
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in_find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
    File "C:\Users\anil.chelladurai\Desktop\06_07\ADHCAT_version2D_Demo.py", line 17, in <module>
import cympy
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
    File "C:\Program Files (x86)\CYME\CYME\cympy\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    os.chdir(cyme_dir)
    NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: strong text'C:\\Users\\anil.chelladurai\\Desktop\\06_07\\dist\\library.zip\\'
```

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what's wrong: You are trying to chdir to a .zip file.

Comment: I am pretty new to programming. Can you explain a bit about how to solve this problem?

Comment: Don't put the directory you want to change to in a zip file. If it has to be, unpack the zip file into a temp directory first.

Comment: I am not creating that zip file. That zip file is created as a result of converting .py file to .exe file

Answer (score 0):

The "frozen importlib..." error is more likely caused by an unsupported python version being used. I suspect that the converter is using another python environment.

If you get your converter to print its python version (without importing tkinter or cympy), you should get a different version that the one which is running the script correctly. The supported version is 3.4 and there are issues to be expected if you try to use another version. This is because python isn't the same, under the hood, from one release to another. Even a minor version can break something.

The following script, while it may appear very simple, should be informative enough to address the issue:

**Python**

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

Run that script in both environments and compare the output. Once you get sure that the right python version is being used, you may want to test the Cyme version as well as testing the `import` of cympy.

**Python**

```
import cympy
print(cympy.version)
```

From that point, everything should be working just fine. If not, it means you got deeper issues in your own python code.

It is very strange, though, that you might want to convert a python script to an executable. The right way to execute python instructions from an executable is to interface the python C Api. Otherwise, the python interpreter is more than suited to run a python script and should be preferred. If converting is an effort to hide the python code or prevent copy, this probably isn't the best approach since there are simple tools that can reveal the python script underneath. Why don't you want to use python for a python script?

The subsequent error, as comments are already pointing out, probably is a good case of "don't do that". Resolving the root issue may also help on that by changing the behavior of your script, hence maybe it won't try to do that anymore.

Good luck!